# UIScrollview:Horizontal Paged uiscrollview with three inner vertical uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

i have above bunch of uiscrollviews in my view..

i have added three scroll-view in one horizontal scollview when user swipe horizontally they can switch between three vertical scroll-view.

when user swipe vertically they can see more data in one of the vertical scroll-view.

in my application when user swipe horizontally they can get information of next date or previous date based on left or right horizontal swipe

i have one method called createScrollview this method returns whole scroll-view with necessary labels image-views & etc...

the vertical scroll-views are placed as following on horizontal scroll-view

```
first vertical scrollview at (0,0,320,480)

second vertical scrollview at (320,0,320,480)

third vertical scrollview at (640,0,320,480)

the Contentsize of horizontal scroll-view is (320*3,480)
```

when View is loaded the contentoffset of horizontalscrollview is set to (320,0) which means user views the center vertical scrollview when page is loaded

when page is loaded three scroll-view is loaded with it's data in following manner

```
in first scroll-view previous date's data,
in second scroll-view current  date's data &
in third scroll-view next date's data,
```

now actually what i want is this...

when user swipe right horizontaly the user should switched from current date to next date & same thing when user  swipes left user should switched from current date to previouse date

at this time when user switch day after date's data should be loaded for next swipe..

i want to make this possible for infinite swipes... & with only three scrollviews..

& one important thing is that user can swipe infinitely in one direction like left or right....

i have seen following question for infinite image scrolling....

[infinite image scolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357018/animation-with-infinite-scrollview) &

[IOS: UIScrollView with an infinite paging view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891958/ios-uiscrollview-with-an-infinite-paging-view)

i want same thing with three vertical scroll-views

Comment: What have you tried? Did you adapt some code of the answers you linked to for your solution?

Comment: Kai yes i tried but i have confusion to how to get it done.... i want same as above links but instead of infinite imageviews i want scrollviews which are generated at each swipes....i want some suggestion & code to get it done properly...pls help

Comment: +1 for giving me nice idea